# How to track resources' (inodes, blocks) usage change upon starting a program

Tags: linux, filesystems, resources

I am supposed to track how file system's usage of resources (i-nodes, blocks) changes before I start a program, after I start a program, delete its executable file, and then finally after I kill its last process.

The problem I reach is that I can't seem to register **any** change in resources even in the very first stage. Below I checked the block and i-node numbers for the root's file system , started firefox (in other terminal), and measured those values again:

```
    [root@12345 ttyid:1 nie cze 07 00:17:47 ~]# which firefox
/usr/bin/firefox
    [root@12345 ttyid:1 nie cze 07 00:17:50 ~]# df /usr/bin/firefox
System plików                    1K-bl   użyte dostępne %uż. zamont. na
    /dev/mapper/fedora_12345-root 8378368 5407812  2970556  65% /
    [root@12345 ttyid:1 nie cze 07 00:18:01 ~]# ps -a
      PID TTY          TIME CMD
     3687 pts/1    00:00:00 ps
    [root@12345 ttyid:1 nie cze 07 00:18:06 ~]# stat -f /dev/mapper   /fedora_12345-root
      Plik: "/dev/mapper/fedora_12345-root"
        ID: 0        długość nazwy: 255     typ: tmpfs
    rozmiar bloku: 4096       podstawowy rozmiar bloku: 4096
    bloków: Razem: 130573     wolnych: 130573     dostępnych: 130573
    Inody: razem: 130573     wolnych: 130163
    [root@12345 ttyid:1 nie cze 07 00:18:11 ~]# ps -a
      PID TTY          TIME CMD
     3697 pts/0    00:00:08 firefox
     3783 pts/1    00:00:00 ps
    [root@12345 ttyid:1 nie cze 07 00:18:41 ~]# stat -f /dev/mapper/fedora_12345-root
      Plik: "/dev/mapper/fedora_12345-root"
        ID: 0        długość nazwy: 255     typ: tmpfs
    rozmiar bloku: 4096       podstawowy rozmiar bloku: 4096
    bloków: Razem: 130573     wolnych: 130573     dostępnych: 130573
    Inody: razem: 130573     wolnych: 130163
```

(I tried it on `firefox` browser, and `nano` and `vim` programs so far; no observed change.)

What options I should use with `df` and `stat` (the two required commands) to successfully track the change in resources? Am I tracking a wrong, constant and similarly-named value or making some other mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stat -f /dev/mapper/fedora_12345-root` returns information about the filesystem containing the device node, which is `/dev`. To return information about a mounted filesystem, you need to look at a file on that filesystem: `stat -f /`. The `df` utility automatically translates mounted block devices to a mount point for them, but `stat` doesn't do this.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably make use of '[strace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace)' &/or '[truss](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=truss)'. Both tools can be used to examine file system operations when a program is ran or running.

For example:

```
$ strace -pf $(ps af | grep "firefox" | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $1}')
```

That command will bind to the process id obtained from 'ps' and follow any child threads it may use.